# How to visualize data from a Postgresql in Kibana?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, diagram

I need to some visualize data from a Postgresql in Kibana. I have also ElasticSearch installed just in case. So how visualize data from a Postgresql in Kibana? Of course, I don't need the whole database, but only data returned by a custom sql query. 
Also, I want it to be as simple as possible, I wouldn't like to use libraries I really don't need to use.

Comment: It seems that there is a fork claiming to support this: https://github.com/sirensolutions/kibi (not an answer, so this was posted as a comment)

Comment: Instead of Kibana you could use this tool for visualizing the data: https://github.com/getredash/redash

Answer (score 5):

Kibana was built with Elastisearch in mind.

Having used it quite a lot in a startup I worked for, I can tell you that even the front-end query DSL (built on Lucene) will only work with Elasticsearch (or might need some serious tweaks).

I would advise you to push your data into Elasticsearch, and just work with Kibana the way it was made for :)